# Passing data to non related components using Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs, components

I'm having trouble receiving the data sent by the Subject. The console log shows that the data gets passed around to everywhere but the final destination. When I subscribe to the subject, nothing happens.

Here is the Shared Service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class SharedService {
    
      public movieId = new Subject<any>;
      
    
      constructor() {}
       
       sendMovieId(data: any)
       {
        this.movieId.next(data);
       }
    }
```

Here is the "sending" component

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { MovieResult } from '../movie-result';
import { SharedService } from '../services/shared.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-details',
  templateUrl: './movie-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-details.component.css']
})
export class MovieDetailsComponent  implements OnInit{
  
  @Input() data!: any;
  
  constructor(private shared: SharedService){

  }

  sendId(details: any)
  {
    this.shared.sendMovieId(details[1]);
   
    
  }

  

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
  }
}
```

Here is the "sending" component html

```
 <div class="row" style="width: 1200px">
      <div class="results" *ngFor="let data of data; let i = index">
        <div  class="card movies" *ngIf="i<8" style="width: 12rem;  ">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{data[3]}}" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title">{{data[0]}}</h3>
            <a routerLink="/movies" (click)="sendId(data)" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: .4em;">See Connecting Movies</a>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the "capturing" component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../services/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  movieData!: any;

  constructor(private shared: SharedService){
    
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shared.movieId.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      
      this.movieData = data;
      this.logData();

    })}

    
    
    logData(){
      console.log(this.movieData);
      
  }
}
```

Comment: If a subscription happens AFTER a value is emitted, the new subscriber will not receive the previous emission.  You could try using `ReplaySubject(1)` instead of plain `Subject` to see if that yields the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Function `sendId` is called and value next'ed to subject when user clicks the link. At this time "capturing" component is not instantiated and there is no subscribers to `movieId` so emmited value is lost.

Use `ReplaySubject` or `BehaviorSubject` that holds last value and always emits even to late subscribers.

Or, as you already use Router, just pass movieId via route parameter to child component.

Comment: How do you know that the component is not yet instantiated?

Comment: @Bishibro Are you sure that component is instantiated? Is "capturing" components `ngOnInit` `subscribe` executed before `senId` call? Do some testing with code to understand component and Router lifecycle. Router will do many tasks before target component gets actually initialized so `click` event handler in "sending" component will be executed much before Router instantintes child component.

Comment: I removed the router and still have the same problem. I have no idea what is causing this issue